# Failure in passing shared variable in main report to subreport select expert

Tags: crystal-reports

I need your assistant in passing a database field called {engine.rptno} to the subreport select expert from the main report. I tried to use shared variable in the main report.

I created a formula in the main report

```
shared numbervar report_number := {engine.rptno};

report_number;
```

In the sub report, I create a formula ("Shared_report_number") and I placed it in the report header. It has the code:

```
shared numbervar report_number;

report_number;
```

I clicked on Select Expert and then I chose the field {engine.rptno} is equal to {@Shared_report_number}, it produces and

error that : the formula cannot be used because it must be evaluated later
Can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to use a `shared` variable, link the main report to the sub-reort on the desired field.

** edit **

Instructions:

- Right click the sub-report and choose `Change Subreport Links...`
- Select the desired field (`engine.rptno`) from the main report (a listbox), then click `>`
- Select the desired field (`engine.rptno`) from the subreport (a picklist), then click `OK`

A record-section formula will be generated in the subreport that resembles:

```
{engine.rptno} = {?Pm-engine.rptno}
```

Comment: Can you assist me more ... What I am trying to do is that I want to pass the report number field which is taken from the database {engine.rptno} to the subreport and to make sure that the subreport doesn't use any other report number. The subreport is having also the field {engine.rptno} and the same tables except that my concern is that it shouldn't take any other report numbers.

So what do you suggest in which way should I pass the {engine.rptno} and to make the subreport take this report no?